# How can I control player movement and player camera at the same time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

So, I was converting a game I made for PC into android and was working with the controls. I was successfully able to implement a joystick for moving the player. And I also added the camera rotation for looking around. But the problem comes when I try to do multiple touches. I can make it work in one order, where either the joystick is used first or the camera is being rotated first. But I cant seem to figure out a way to recognise what was touched first. Here is my code:

I am importing these values to another script which I downloaded from the asset store. But I think the problem is here, if u want the other script, I will provide it :)

```
private void Update()
    {
        horizontal = joystick.Horizontal();
        vertical = joystick.Vertical();
        Debug.Log("Horizontal: " + horizontal + " Vertical: " + vertical);
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            int id = touch.fingerId;
            if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(id)) { return; }
            if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) || (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Canceled)) { return;        }
        }
        
        if (Input.touchCount > 1 && Input.GetTouch(1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            if(lastItem == "movement")
            {
                mouseHorizontal = (Input.GetTouch(1).deltaPosition.x * 0.08f);
                mouseVertical = (Input.GetTouch(1).deltaPosition.y * 0.08f);
            }

            if(lastItem == "camera")
            {
                mouseHorizontal = (Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x * 0.08f);
                mouseVertical = (Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y * 0.08f);
            }
        }

        else if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            if(horizontal > 0 || vertical > 0)
            {
                mouseHorizontal = 0;
                mouseVertical = 0;
                lastItem = "movement";
            }
            else
            {
                mouseHorizontal = (Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x * 0.08f);
                mouseVertical = (Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.y * 0.08f);
                lastItem = "camera";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            mouseHorizontal = 0;
            mouseVertical = 0;
        }


        Debug.Log("Camera= " + "Horizontal: " + mouseHorizontal + " Vertical: " + mouseVertical);
    }
```

I tried some ways by getting the previous values, but that didnt work(maybe my logic was wrong). And so I resorted to a simpler one using strings. I think I implemented it right, but still it doesnt seem to work. I am very new to dealing with touches so I'd appreciate if someone can help me :)

Comment: As far as I understand the index used in `GetTouch` is not necessarily persistent across frames - see [`Touch.fingerId`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html) instead of the `lastItem` you might rather want to store the fingerId of according touches and use those instead ... in general it is a bit hard to understand what exact behavior you expect your code to have and what happens instead

Comment: The behaviour I expect is proper control.  I want to move the player and control the camera at the same time. The problem is I can only use either the joystick or the camera at one time. and when I try to use both at exact same time, it causes either the joystick to work as the control for the camera or the camera to not move at all.

Comment: You use the `mouseHorizontal` / `mouseVertical` for both apparently .. quite hard to tell as said as we don't see the rest of your code

Comment: So what part of my code should I provide? I'll definitely provide it if that is required

Comment: The thing is currently we can only see you assigning the touch values in some fields ... using the same fields both for camera and joystick ... so we can't know how exactly you are using those later on